How to know if a video file is original video or screencast
I have a video file provided by someone else for work. I won't process the video if it's screen-recorded from another device or from another app. So how can I check if the video above is the original video or if the video has been recorded from another device's screen or if the video is a screen recording from a computer or phone. thank you.
Some of the videos they sent me had file names containing the word "record" or they were for screen recording so I recognized them. But there are many cases where they have renamed the video and cropped the frame so I can't tell if the video is a screen recording or not.
